# Appending header and footer to pdf add on in Plone

Tags: plone

I am using the aws.pdfbook add on in plone. This add on uses htmldoc and converts a page to pdf which can be printed or downloaded. I would like to append a header and a footer to the pdf-ed content. How can i do this?. I am fairly new to plone and do not know where the code for add ons is stored. I would also be grateful if anyone can give me the code to append a header and a footer to the pdf. I am using plone 4.2 on a linux box.Thanks.

Comment: I just asked 4 questions and answered two of them myself. two other questions are still open.:)

Comment: You can also try EEA PDF Plone Add-on based on wkhtmltopdf. See my PloneConf 2014 talk about it: https://vimeo.com/110982540#t=2467s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. This is quite straightforward. Go to ZMI> portal_view_customizations> printlayout (aws.pdfbook.interfaces.IAWSPDFBOOKLayer) and add the header in  tag.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could actually check the [HTMLDOC documentation](https://www.msweet.org/documentation/project1/HTMLDOC.html) yourself.

Headers and Footers are configurable using HTML comments.

Since aws.pdfbook uses custom templates per content-types

https://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/aws.pdfbook/trunk/aws/pdfbook/browser/templates/

you should be able to customize the related template by using z3c.jbot inside your own policy package in order to override one of these templates.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Can i just go into the portal_view_customizationa in ZMI and directly customize the code there?. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: When I say z3c.jbot then I mean use z3c.jbot